# Single vs Multi Sub Program

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am busy with a VBA Code for automatically importing and re-sizing images into a Word Document at specific places, it will also provide error messages for various situations.

My question is:

Is it better to use and call a Sub which is specific for a part of the code or to have one long code which is divided into sections with comments.

I am currently using one long Sub and trying to see if I can get the same result by calling each sub separately, doing this I struggle with getting global variables or string assigned to be available in all modules and subs.

I understand for sharing the code having one long Sub is beneficial.

Comment: I would suggest only one for your consideration- if you don't repeat the same/similar snippet of code within your long sub then it is ok. If you have to repeat part of code you should have them in separate Sub. For sure there are some other points to consider but start with that first.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it. There is a loop in my code which searches for a certain element in the document and then there are not any repeats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the additional experience now, I can see that multi-sub programs are beneficial for repeating for repeating parts of the code as @KazimerzJawor mentioned.

Also, apart from having loads of comments which is a must, it helps to divide you code up to manageable parts which contains smaller ideas of the main coding.